# How to use sensor_msgs/Image message?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

- I'm a beginner on ROS.
- I want to use a topic "/usb_cam/image_raw". (this
  topic is usb_cam package)
- So I made a package, and a Subscriber.
- However,   there is still error in the
  catkin_make process.
- How can I write
  CMakeList ?

main source

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Image.h"

void msgCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
        ROS_INFO("height = %d, width = %d",msg->height, msg->width);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        ros::init(argc,argv,"cam_data");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;

        ros::Subscriber cam_sub = nh.subscribe("/usb_cam/image_raw",100,msgCallback);
        ros::spin();

        return 0;
}
```

CMakeList

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test_cam)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
)


 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   sensor_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES test_cam
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp sensor_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(receive_cam src/receive_cam.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(test_cam ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
#add_dependencies(receive_cam test_cam_cpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246859/how-to-use-sensor_msgs/image-message?/) by [anonymous28394](https://answers.ros.org/users/28394/anonymous28394/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have several problems:

1. If you are going to use the `generate_msgs()` macro to ensure message dependencies are built, you'll need a `find_package` call for `message_generation`, you'll also need to list `message_runtime` as a CATKIN_DEPENDS in your `catkin_package` macro. You'll also need to add `message_generation` as a build dependency and `message_runtime` as a run dependency in your package.xml. Documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html).
2. You have what appear to be incorrectly specified dependencies in your `catkin_package` macro. Is `system_lib` actually a CMake project containing libraries that you depend on? Are you providing the `test_cam` library for use with other catkin packages? Documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html?highlight=catkin_package#catkin_package)
3. You need to link your executable against libraries that your package depends on with `target_link_libraries`.

Here's a version that should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test_cam)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  message_generation
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES sensor_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp message_runtime sensor_msgs
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(receive_cam src/receive_cam.cpp)
target_link_libraries(receive_cam ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-31**:
Note: @breeze6478 is writing a *subscriber*. `generate_message(..)` is typically not needed/used in that case, as he *depends on* `sensor_msgs`. I think the only problem (but this is a guess) was that `generate_messages(..)` is there. It's not needed. And of course the `test_cam` etc.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-10-31**:
That is for sure correct, unless the package is defining custom messages, no call to `generate_messages()` should be needed. Without more info on the package, it was tough to tell whether I should delete the call or fix the call.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-10-31**:
If he is only writing a subscriber, I should have probably just deleted the call.